# VSCode macros extension wrong sequence

Tags: visual-studio-code, macros, command, sequence, key-bindings

I'm currently trying to get a shortcut which opens the default and user keybindings in json side by side (pretty much the same what VSCode already provides for the settings.json). Since VSCode does not support that in itself, I tried to do it with the [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros&ssr=false#overview) extension.

My code looks the following:

```
"macros": {
    "openKeybindings": [
        "workbench.action.openDefaultKeybindingsFile",
        "workbench.action.openGlobalKeybindingsFile",
        "workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup",
    ],
},
```

I can now trigger this macro with:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+k",        "command": "macros.openKeybindings" },
```

What I am thinking this macro should be executing is:

1. Open the default keybindins.json
2. Open the user keybindins.json
3. Move the user keybindins.json to a new editor window to the right so they are side by side

---

My problem now is, the macros does not seem to execute these three commands in sequence. What actually happens if I press ctrl+alt+k is that the default **and** user keybindings.json get opened in the new editor window to the right.

Can anyone explain to me why the macro does not execute the commands in order and maybe give me a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed that problem with this [issue](https://github.com/geddski/macros/pull/13) on the github of this macro